# Using PHP Class PulseConnect, only getting the first 50 results

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, soap

this is my first time asking in here directly, but I can't find the answer in any place. I'm pretty new making connections to an API using SOAP, and I'm using the class pulseconnect from this link https://github.com/BrookLab/pulseconnect and Codeigniter, and I get the connection without a problem, but, when I execute the function "getMailingReportSummaries" it does not matter what I pass inside the array as a parameter every time I only get the first 50 results, even when the array is blank. I'm sorry if this is to obvious but I'm stuck with this and I really need your help. Thank you.

This is how I'm making the call:

Function inside the Php Class:

```
    public function getMailingReportSummaries($reportCriteria)
{
    return $this->returnResult($this->_client->__soapCall('getMailingReportSummaries',$reportCriteria), __FUNCTION__);
}
```

My code...

```
$criteria = array('2015-05-10','2015-12-10','Mailings','EMAIL','','100','','','');
    //$criteria = array('From-Date'=>'2015-05-10', 'To-Date'=>'2015-12-28', 'Type'=>'Mailings','Channel'=>'EMAIL','ID'=>'','100','Mailing Title'=>'','List Title'=>'','List External ID'=>'');
    //$response = cvf_convert_object_to_array($postup_api->getMailingReportSummaries($fromDate, $toDate, $mailingType, $channel, $listID, $limit));
    $response = cvf_convert_object_to_array($postup_api->getMailingReportSummaries($criteria));
```

If you need more info about what I'm using please just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like things fall back to a default of 50... I have no experience with that class or API. But could it be that the `'100'` you specify in the criteria should be `100` instead? So a number, not a string?

Comment: Thank you arkascha, I tried that also, but I get the same thing every time...

Comment: OK, so what does the documentation of that call say? Can you link the methods fingerprint? Maybe it requires an associative array for the criteria? That would make _much_ more sense from an API point of view...

Comment: Well finally solved it... the correct way to declare the method to call it is:

`public function getMailingReportSummaries($reportCriteria)
    {
        return $this->returnResult($this->_client->getMailingReportSummaries($reportCriteria), __FUNCTION__);
    }`

And the array needs to be associative like this:

`$criteria = array('fromdate'=>'2015-05-01', 'todate'=>'2015-10-02','type'=>'','listID'=>'','limit'=>100, 'listtitle'=>'NAP - Main List');`

Thank you arkascha for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally solved it... the correct way to declare the method to call it is: public function getMailingReportSummaries($reportCriteria) { return $this->returnResult($this->_client->getMailingReportSummaries($reportCriteria), **FUNCTION**); } And the array needs to be associative like this: $criteria = array('fromdate'=>'2015-05-01', 'todate'=>'2015-10-02','type'=>'','listID'=>'','limit'=>100, 'listtitle'=>'NAP - Main List'); Thank you arkascha for your help.